# Adding KeyAdapter to JComponent

Tags: java, swing, awt, keylistener

Trying to add a keyListener to this component, however I am getting no response. I want it to be respond whenever the component is displayed in the scroll Panel. I've been able to get it to work when adding it to JPanels. Is there something I should be doing differently for my component?

This the the Component I seek to implement Keylistener on.

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.event.MouseInputListener;

import java.awt.FontMetrics;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;



public class PhotoComponent extends JComponent implements MouseInputListener{
    
    private ImageIcon pic;
    
    Boolean checkVac=false;
    Boolean checkSchool=false;
    Boolean checkFam= false;
    Boolean checkWork = false;
    Boolean flipped = false;
    Boolean penButton=false;
    boolean textButton=false;

    
    public PhotoComponent(){
    }

    public PhotoComponent(ImageIcon p){
        pic=p;
        setRequestFocusEnabled(true);
        requestFocus();
        addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                System.out.println("hello");
                }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
        if(pic==null){
            return new Dimension(0,0);
        }
        return new Dimension(pic.getIconWidth(), pic.getIconHeight());
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        pic.paintIcon(this, g, 0, 0);   
    }
  
}
```

This is the program I am calling it on.

```
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.event.MouseInputListener;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;

public class Base extends JFrame {
    private JPanel  statusContainer;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private JMenuBar jmb;
    private JMenu file;
    private JMenuItem importbutton;
    private ArrayList<PhotoComponent> picList;
    private int picIndex;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Base();
    }

    public Base(){
        setTitle("Placeholder");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500,500);
        setResizable(true);
        
        mainProgram();

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void mainProgram(){
        jmb = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(jmb);
        file=new JMenu("File");
        statusContainer = new JPanel();
        add(statusContainer, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


        jmb.add(file);

        importbutton = new JMenuItem("Import");

        //currentPic= new PhotoComponent();
        picList= new ArrayList<PhotoComponent>(5);
        picIndex = 0;
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        
        
        add(scrollPane);
        
        importbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent fo){
                JFileChooser chooser= new JFileChooser("");
                FileFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Graphics", "jpg","jpeg","png");
                chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
                chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
                chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
                int response = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

                if(response == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                   File[] chosen = chooser.getSelectedFiles();
                    for (File f:chosen) {
                        if(f.isDirectory()){
                            File[] temp=f.listFiles();
                            for (File x:temp){;
                                ImageIcon ii =new ImageIcon(x.getAbsolutePath());
                                picList.add(new PhotoComponent(ii));
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            ImageIcon ii =new ImageIcon(f.getAbsolutePath());
                            picList.add(new PhotoComponent(ii));
                            }
                            
                        }
                    scrollPane.setViewportView(picList.get(picIndex));
                    ///mainScroll.addMouseListener(picList.get(pos));
                    scrollPane.setVisible(true);
                    
                    validate();
                    }
                else {
                    JOptionPane.showInputDialog("oops somethings wrong");
                }
                    
                }
                
            });
    

        file.add(importbutton);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) For Swing, we typically use [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) rather than the lower level `KeyListener`. 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). A compilable, runnable example of this should take no more than 40-50 lines of code.

Comment: Additionally to comment of @AndrewThompson : you probably should add `setFocusable(true);` in constructor of your `PhotoComponent`. If it doesn't help, please provide a [mcve] as it was suggested by Andrew.

Comment: *requestFocus();* - 1) Read the API. This method should not be used. The API will tell you the appropriate method to be used. 2) adding this statement in the constructor will do nothing. You can only request focus on a component that is visible on the frame. In the constructor the component has not been added to the frame. 3) Why are you now using a KeyListener? The problem with your last code was not the MouseListener itself. The problem was the code in the MouseListener. You deleted your question before an answer could be posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ther're many ways how to solve this problem. One of them use `KeyEventDispatcher` if you need some global key mappings.

Another way is to add `KeyListener` to you parent `JFrame` to catch key pressed event and delegate it to the current component. Check this out!

***P.S.** I am not saying that this is an optimal solution, but I have checked it - it works. You can use it or it can be a start point for your own solution.*

```
public class Base extends JFrame implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

    private final JPanel statusContainer = new JPanel();
    private final JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    private final JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
    private final JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
    private final JMenuItem importButton = new JMenuItem("Import");

    private List<PhotoComponent> pictures = Collections.emptyList();
    private int pictureIndex = -1;

    public static void main(String... args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new Base().setVisible(true));
    }

    public Base() {
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        setTitle("Placeholder");
        setJMenuBar(menubar);

        add(statusContainer, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(scrollPane);

        file.add(importButton);
        menubar.add(file);
        setResizable(true);

        importButton.addActionListener(this);
        addKeyListener(this);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500, 500);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if (event.getSource() == importButton)
            onImportButton();
    }

    private void onImportButton() {
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        fileChooser.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("Graphics", "jpg", "jpeg", "png"));
        fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
        fileChooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);

        if (fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            pictures = getPictures(fileChooser);
            pictureIndex = pictures.isEmpty() ? -1 : 0;

            scrollPane.setViewportView(pictureIndex == -1 ? null : pictures.get(pictureIndex));
            scrollPane.setVisible(true);

            validate();
        } else
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog("oops somethings wrong");
    }

    private static List<PhotoComponent> getPictures(JFileChooser fileChooser) {
        List<PhotoComponent> pictures = new ArrayList<>();

        for (File fileOrDir : fileChooser.getSelectedFiles())
            for (File file : getFiles(fileOrDir))
                pictures.add(new PhotoComponent(new ImageIcon(file.getAbsolutePath())));

        return pictures;
    }

    private static List<File> getFiles(File fileOrDir) {
        if (fileOrDir.isDirectory())
            return Arrays.asList(Objects.requireNonNull(fileOrDir.listFiles()));
        return Collections.singletonList(fileOrDir);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
        if (pictureIndex != -1)
            pictures.get(pictureIndex).keyPressed(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) {
    }
}

public class PhotoComponent extends JComponent {

    private final ImageIcon picture;

    public PhotoComponent(ImageIcon picture) {
        this.picture = picture;
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
        System.out.println("keyPressed: " + event.getKeyCode());
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(picture.getIconWidth(), picture.getIconHeight());
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        picture.paintIcon(this, g, 0, 0);
    }

}
```